# VBA / Excel - Fill formula down till last row in column & select a file

Tags: excel, vba

I am new here and want help with VBA for Excel

Each day we get some data from the system.

So i need to:

1. open the new file (fixed location)
2. Insert 3 columns & Name them
3. Open the old File (fixed location)
4. insert the formulas for each column
5. **Apply the formula for all the rows, as in (today the new file has 20 rows, tomorrow it might have 40)**
6. copy / paste only the values (so that the formula goes away and only the value remains)
7. save it under a specific name

This is the code i have so far (written with record macro since i have limited knowledge of VBA)

```
Sub EstrHC()
'
' EstrHC Macro
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    ChDir "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\user\Desktop\outputHC.csv", Origin _
        :=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
        Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), _
        Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15 _
        , 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), _
        Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array( _
        28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(32, 1), Array(33, 1), Array(34, 1), _
        Array(35, 1), Array(36, 1), Array(37, 1), Array(38, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(40, 1), Array( _
        41, 1), Array(42, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(44, 1), Array(45, 1), Array(46, 1), Array(47, 1), _
        Array(48, 1), Array(49, 1), Array(50, 1), Array(51, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Assegnato"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Esito"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Note"
    Range("F1:H1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 14.43
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 13.57
    Range("F2").Select
    ChDir "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Estr\HC"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Estr\HC\HC.xlsx"
    Windows("outputHC.csv").Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[HC.xlsx]20200604 Rds da gestire'!C5:C6,2,0)"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[HC.xlsx]20200604 Rds da gestire'!C5:C7,3,0)"
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'[HC.xlsx]20200604 Rds da gestire'!C5:C8,4,0)"
    Range("F2:H2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:H15")
    Range("F2:H15").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("F1:H1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("H8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .KeepChangeHistory = True
        .ChangeHistoryDuration = 30
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\user\Desktop\2020 Rds da gestire.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, AccessMode:=xlShared
    Windows("Cartel1.xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Firstly, since you use only `General` format when opens CSV file, whole `FieldInfo`may be missing. It is good to be used only if you need some different format for some columns. Then, selecting/activating is something unnecessary which only consumes Excel resources and do not bring any benefit. So, use `Columns("F:F").Insert...` instead of selecting it first. Use `Range("F1").Value = "Assegnato"` instead of firstly selected and inappropriate using of `FormulaR1C1`, even if it works. For knowing the last filled row, it must be calculated `lastR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(XlUp).Row`.

Comment: `Dim lastR As Long`. Copy - Paste it is also good be done without selecting. `Selection.End(xlDown)` may return a wrong range if blank cells exist in the range. Use the way I suggested above (`lastR`) to define it. No `Selection.AutoFill` needed in VBA. It is enough to place the formula at once: `Range("F2:F" & lastR).FormulaR1C1 =  
 "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[HC.xlsx]20200604 Rds da gestire'!C5:C6,2,0)"`. And simple use `Formula` instead of `FormulaR1C1` due to the fact that it is easier to be read/understood (visually, I mean). Even if Excel shows this inconvenient formula on record macros...

Comment: Still alive? Mai trăiești?